# Outlook - Search folders for all emails To or From a certain domain?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I manage many clients, and it would be helpful to have email folders with all email to of from each client.  I can do that now using Search Folders where From is @example.com  That works fine, but does not include my emails To that domain.
I am hoping for a reasonable solution to this - not programming or customizing outlook in awkward ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a search folder by a specific email domain name in Outlook.
Just refer to this link: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3936-outlook-search-folder-email-domain-name.html

Comment: That spammy site shows exactly what i do now. It is just for From domains,  not also To